# ZFS didn't released all allocated space after multiple dataset destroy

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I had multiple datasets, deleted them all with multiple commands.
At first I saw that "root" dataset occupies like 100Gb, then 50Gb, then 20Gb... and it got "stuck" on 535M.

OS: FreebSD 11.0

I tried to "google it", but no result. No visible files in mountpoint /zm. Any insights?

```
zfs list -t all -o space -r zm_ssd512
NAME       AVAIL   USED  USEDSNAP  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  USEDCHILD
zm_ssd512   461G   535M         0     96K              0       535M

zfs get all zm_ssd512
NAME       PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
zm_ssd512  type                  filesystem             -
zm_ssd512  creation              Wed Jun 21 12:02 2017  -
zm_ssd512  used                  535M                   -
zm_ssd512  available             461G                   -
zm_ssd512  referenced            96K                    -
zm_ssd512  compressratio         1.00x                  -
zm_ssd512  mounted               no                     -
zm_ssd512  quota                 none                   default
zm_ssd512  reservation           none                   default
zm_ssd512  recordsize            128K                   default
zm_ssd512  mountpoint            /zm                    local
zm_ssd512  sharenfs              off                    default
zm_ssd512  checksum              on                     default
zm_ssd512  compression           lz4                    local
zm_ssd512  atime                 on                     default
zm_ssd512  devices               on                     default
zm_ssd512  exec                  on                     default
zm_ssd512  setuid                on                     default
zm_ssd512  readonly              off                    default
zm_ssd512  jailed                off                    default
zm_ssd512  snapdir               hidden                 default
zm_ssd512  aclmode               discard                default
zm_ssd512  aclinherit            restricted             default
zm_ssd512  canmount              on                     default
zm_ssd512  xattr                 on                     default
zm_ssd512  copies                1                      default
zm_ssd512  version               5                      -
zm_ssd512  utf8only              off                    -
zm_ssd512  normalization         none                   -
zm_ssd512  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
zm_ssd512  vscan                 off                    default
zm_ssd512  nbmand                off                    default
zm_ssd512  sharesmb              off                    default
zm_ssd512  refquota              none                   default
zm_ssd512  refreservation        none                   default
zm_ssd512  primarycache          all                    default
zm_ssd512  secondarycache        all                    default
zm_ssd512  usedbysnapshots       0                      -
zm_ssd512  usedbydataset         96K                    -
zm_ssd512  usedbychildren        535M                   -
zm_ssd512  usedbyrefreservation  0                      -
zm_ssd512  logbias               latency                default
zm_ssd512  dedup                 off                    default
zm_ssd512  mlslabel                                     -
zm_ssd512  sync                  standard               default
zm_ssd512  refcompressratio      1.00x                  -
zm_ssd512  written               96K                    -
zm_ssd512  logicalused           178M                   -
zm_ssd512  logicalreferenced     35K                    -
zm_ssd512  volmode               default                default
zm_ssd512  filesystem_limit      none                   default
zm_ssd512  snapshot_limit        none                   default
zm_ssd512  filesystem_count      none                   default
zm_ssd512  snapshot_count        none                   default
zm_ssd512  redundant_metadata    all                    default
```

Update: zdb -bb gives this (among other lines). So now I need to find out what is "SPA space map".

```
44.2K   183M    178M    535M   12.1K    1.02    99.88  SPA space map
```

Comment: How many filesystems did you delete and how big were they?

Comment: There was 4 “child” datasets (zm_ssd512/var/db/mysql/somedb). All of them empty except last one. It was filled up with like 400Gb data (compressed with lz4, real data size was around 800gb). And up to 1000 files.

Comment: I have experienced a similar behavior with about the same data contents as you, but on an older pool version. Sorry to be of no help, all I could find was http://zfs-discuss.opensolaris.narkive.com/ADW21Qso/zfs-space-map-optimalization . In my case, I destroyed the file system because I did not have time to evaluate the exact cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZFS space maps are internal data structures that describe the free and allocated space being used by ZFS. As you delete data, the space maps should also shrink, but there are limitations as to how much they can shrink as all of ZFS's metadata need to be accounted for in the space maps as well.